# Как считывать нажатие комбинаций клавиш?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++14

Считывание комбинаций должно происходить даже если окно программы не активно.

Вот что я написал:

```
#pragma once
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include "winuser.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <complex>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace ::std;


void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x20) == -32767 && GetAsyncKeyState(0x44) == -32767)
        {
            cout << "SPACE + D" << endl;
        }
        Sleep(50);
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Но это работает очень криво. Нужно по 5 раз нажимать сочетание и тогда, возможно, он напишет  "SPACE + D", как можно решить эту проблему??

Comment: Используйте функцию `RegisterHotKey`. `GetAsyncKeyState` делает не то, что вы думаете.

Comment: Я вас люблю и ненавижу. Это работает божественно! Но чтобы понять понять как это все использовать мне пришлось потратить 1-2 часа и облазить 6-7 форумов @user7860670